# python paho mqtt can not connect to mqtts with username and password

Tags: python, mqtt

The following python code on my raspberrypi doesn't connect to my mqtt broker, it just hangs after printing `Connecting...`:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("test")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


client = mqtt.Client(client_id="",clean_session=True,userdata=None,protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311,transport="tcp")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.username_pw_set(username="stackoverflow",password="stackoverflow")
print("Connecting...")
client.connect("learn.evermight.net", 9101, 10)
client.loop_forever()
```

What did I do wrong with my Python code?

---

**Command Line Success**

I confirmed that my mqtt does work because I can subscribe from terminal with this command:

```
mosquitto_sub -h learn.evermight.net -p 9101 -t "test" -u "stackoverflow" -P "stackoverflow" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

And I will see messages in my terminal as soon as I run this command from another terminal

```
mosquitto_pub -h learn.evermight.net -p 9101 -t "test" -u "stackoverflow" -P "stackoverflow" -m "hello world" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

What is wrong with my python code?

---

**NodeJS Success**

Additionally, the following NodeJS code also works for connecting and publishing to my MQTT server.

```
const mqtt = require('async-mqtt');

  try{
    const client = await mqtt.connectAsync("mqtts://learn.evermight.net",{
      port:9101,
      host:"mqtts://learn.evermight.net",
      username:"stackoverflow",
      password:"stackoverflow",
      connectTimeout:5000,
      protocolId:"MQIsdp",
      protocolVersion:3,
      encoding:"utf8",
      keepalive: 60
    });
    await client.publish("test","hello world");
    await client.end();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

---

**Website JavaScript Success**

And the following code can also connect to a websocket port via web browser javascript website, subscribe to the `test` topic and receive published messages (note that my websockets use port 9102)

```
import Paho from "paho-mqtt";

const client = new Paho.Client("learn.evermight.net",9102,"WebBrowser");
  client.onConnectionLost = response=>console.log("lostMQTTConnection: " +(response.errorCode !== 0 ? response.errorMessage : "Unknown MQTT Error" ));
  client.onMessageArrived = message=>console.log(message.payloadString);
  client.connect({
    onSuccess:_=>client.subscribe("test"),
    useSSL:true,
    userName:"stackoverflow",
    password:"stackoverflow",
  });
```

Comment: why do you know if it hangs ? `loop_forever()` should runs code all the time until you kill it.

Comment: as for me all problem can be `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/`. When I run your code with my broker then it runs, and when I run `mosquitto_pub` without `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/` then it also runs but I get `Error: Connection refused` when I use `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/`. Probably in code you would have to use something similar to `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/`

Comment: @furas I updated my code to give real credentials to my mqtt server and I give real working examples in bash, nodejs and plain javascript.  The only thing that fails is my python code.  Does my server work for your python script?

Comment: it doesn't work with Python. It works only with `mosquitto_sub/mosquitto_pub` so I can connect. There are command `client.tls_set()` and `client.tls_set_context()` and maybe they could help. But I never had to use it. I have own MTTQ in local network so I didn't bother to use `certs`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that I can connect if I add this command without arguments

```
client.tls_set()
```

---

In [paho documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#option-functions) at the end of description for `tls_set()` you can see

```
Must be called before connect*().
```

but it works for me even after `client.connect()`

---

In the same domentation you can see that without arguments it uses defult system settings

```
By default, on Python 2.7.9+ or 3.4+,  
the default certification authority of the system is used. 

On older Python version this parameter is mandatory.
```

---

It is needed only if `mosquitto_sub`/`mosquitto_pub` needs `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/`.
If `mosquitto_sub`/`mosquitto_pub` works without `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/` then don't use it.

---

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code", rc)
    client.subscribe("test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic, msg.payload)


client = mqtt.Client(client_id="", clean_session=True, userdata=None, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport="tcp")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.tls_set()  # <--- even without arguments

client.username_pw_set(username="stackoverflow", password="stackoverflow")
print("Connecting...")
client.connect("learn.evermight.net", 9101, 10)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: That worked!  I found out that I can also leave the constructor empty like this `client=mqtt.Client()`. Just the `client.tls_set()` did the trick