# Mqtt broker connection with username and password

Tags: python, encryption, mqtt, broker

It's my first time trying to connect to a mqtt broker and it's not really going great. I've been trying to get data from the broker but am unable to figure out how to connect. I've been handed a username, password, port and encrypted port aswell as "Topics. When trying to connect the "client.connect"-line responds with "0". I changed the username and password and I still get the same result so there is something wrong with my configuration. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm running python 3.6.5

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time


username="temp"
password="temp"

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("extapi/data/esm")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set(username, password)


client.connect("example.io", 1883, 60)
```

Comment: have you checked it already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479786/python-paho-mqtt-can-not-connect-to-mqtts-with-username-and-password